# SQL - How to convert time to decimal more than 24h

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that show me times of production. Today I detect it fails when time is more than 24 hours. I use `datediff` but it doesn't work with more than 24h and make sense.

The `u_daily_work_alb.u_diferencial_machine` is where I store the time value. If the time is `23:00:00` works but more than that won't.

The error is:
 `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

```
CASE WHEN LEN(u_machines_alb.u_reference) > 1 THEN 
    MAX(convert(float, datediff(second, 0, u_daily_work_alb.u_diferencial_machine) / (60.0 * 60.0))) 
END AS timeDecimal
```

The `u_daily_work_alb.u_diferencial_machine` column stores this values:
[image]

The last line return the error reported.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: @user3242861 . . . I'm a bit baffled.  You are running code using an invalid constant value.  Just don't use that constant value to get rid of the error.  I have no idea how this expression relates to "times of production".

Comment: This an example to show you that works with less than 24h. The time value is stored in database. @GordonLinoff

Comment: . . It is not stored in a SQL Server database with a value equal to or greater than 24 hours.

Comment: There's no conversion to `datetime` in this snippet.

Comment: I update the question, so you can understand better. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @user3242861 the question is getting *harder* to understand. Post the table schema so we can understand what `u_diferencial_machine` is. Could it be that it's *NOT* a datetime at all, and SQL Server complains that it can't convert that number or string to datetime?. There's no point in calculating the difference from `0` in the first place. Post SQL code that can reproduce the problem - table creation script, input data (ie INSERT statements), query, expected output.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this case? can you replace `0` with some other value?

Comment: You're trying to convert Time value to decimal, but there's no 24:00:00 in a day. Even datetime column wouldn't store 24:00:00 in a column because it would be 00:00:00. If you run your query with 23:59:59 it works. The question is how is your Datetime column can store incorrect datetime? And how it could be more than 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the computation on an invalid time and just using a constant?

```
(CASE WHEN LEN(u_machines_alb.u_reference) > 1
      THEN MAX(CONVERT(float, 1.0))
 END) AS timeDecimal
```

If you are storing the data as a string, then use `try_convert()`:

```
(CASE WHEN LEN(u_machines_alb.u_reference) > 1 AND
           TRY_CONVERT(time, u_daily_work_alb.u_diferencial_machine) IS NULL
      THEN 1.0
 END) AS timeDecimal
```

Or perhaps:

```
(CASE WHEN LEN(u_machines_alb.u_reference) > 1
      THEN MAX(datediff(second, 0,
                        TRY_CONVERT(time, u_daily_work_alb.u_diferencial_machine)
                       )
               ) / (60.0 * 60.0) 
END AS timeDecimal
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand this question correctly, you are looking for the date difference expressed as a decimal? If you want the output of the datediff division to be a float, you need to convert the divisor to a float before dividing.

Please see if this gives you the desired result
`select MAX(datediff(second, 0, u_machines_alb.u_reference) / Convert(float, 86400))`